# Unique from list or null in Linq?

Tags: linq

I have a list of strings, and want to use a single line of Linq to return the list's unique value (if there is one) or null, otherwise.  In other words:

```
 ["a","a","a","a","a"] returns "a"
 ["a"] returns "a"

 ["a","a","a","a","b"] returns null
 ["a","b","c"] returns null
 [] returns null
```

I assume I would use IEnumerable.Distinct() to collapse the list to its unique values, but I don't know how to do the "single or null" (SingleOrDefault() throws an exception if there's more than one item; FirstOrDefault() will always return the first item, and won't return null if there's two or more like I want.)

Any ideas?  I'm just really curious if there's a simple way to do this in a single line that I'm overlooking.  Bonus points if you don't have to write an extension method to make it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
col.Distinct().Count() == 1? col.First() : null;
```

Comment: Gah, I wrote mine backwards!

Answer (score 1):

Would this do?

```
 col.Distinct().Count() > 1 ? null : col.Distinct().First();
```

Updated to handle empty collection

```
 col.Count() == 0 ? null : col.Distinct().Count() > 1 ? null : col.Distinct().First();
```

Comment: Will throw an exception when `col` is empty.

Comment: col.Distinct().Count() > 1 ? : null : col.First();